# Hibernate returns last row n times

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate core 5.4.33.Final, and mysql-connector 8.0.22.
DB MySql org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.
My problem occurs on previous release too.

Running a simple SQL query on a single table, no join, returns only last record for n times, where n is the correct records number.

HQL Query

```
SELECT ig.id, ig.codice 
FROM ImpiantiGestitiDto as ig
```

Schema:

```
id=integer autoincrement
idPalestra=integer 
codice=varchar(6) 
numero=char(3)
codice_descrizione_impianto=varchar(6)
```

ImpiantiGestitiDto=Dto

This is my code. I don’t use loop.

```
Query<Object> query = session.createQuery(hql);
result = query.getResultList();
```

The mysql-connector run the query succesfully:

```
StandardRowReader - ---Processing Row---
Extracted JDBC value [0] - [1]
Extracted JDBC value [1] - [000.00]
StandardRowReader - ---Processing Row---
Extracted JDBC value [0] - [2]
Extracted JDBC value [1] - [000.01]
StandardRowReader - ---Processing Row---
Extracted JDBC value [0] - [3]
Extracted JDBC value [1] - [000.02]
StandardRowReader - ---Processing Row---
Extracted JDBC value [0] - [4]
Extracted JDBC value [1] - [000.03]
```

Output on getResultList(); Wrong!

```
[[4,"000.03"],[4,"000.03"],[4,"000.03"],[4,"000.03"]]
```

I think the problem occurs in:
-org.hibernate.sql.results.spi package;
-class ListResultsConsumer;
-method Consume.

in following loop, results.add(row) ; instructions occurs the error.
Why occurs the problem? Can you help me? Thank you!

```
while (rowProcessingState.next()) {     
    final R row = rowReader.readRow( rowProcessingState, processingOptions );    
    boolean add = true;     
    if ( uniqueRows ) {         
       if ( results.contains( row ) ) { 
        add = false;        
       }
    }   
    if ( add ) {        
       results.add( row );  
    }   
    rowProcessingState.finishRowProcessing(); 
}
```

Using the query

```
FROM ImpiantiGestitiDto order by id
```

it’s works.

Using the query

```
SELECT id, codice FROM ImpiantiGestitiDto order by id
```

does not work.

I have to use the second query because the table ImpiantiGestitiDto is joined to another table and I have to use the WHERE clause.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try the 5.4 versions. Current latest is `5.4.23.Final`. It's generally not a good idea to use incomplete versions like Alphas. Stuff not working properly is to be expected.

Comment: The problem occurs with previous versions too.